# Intermittent Issue Setting UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift

I have a perplexing problem that I hope someone can give me some insight or direction on solving.

My app is very simple. It's a series of views with UISwitches and labels that function as a guided interview for selecting a group of products for a customer. In the end, it takes all the variables stored in a class and uses them to build a PDF proposal.

Everything works great, except for on rare occasion. I have been present twice for someone using the app, and when they go to previous screens, it fails to set the UISwitch elements in the view. With a bit more playing it then starts to behave as expected.

I know that the variables are still stored correctly because if you generate the PDF while it's demonstrating this behavior, all of the content is present that those previous answers should have generated.

All of the variables are stored in a class which gets instanced as newTracker:

```
class AnswerTracker: NSObject {

    var someVariable1: Bool = false
    var someVariable2: Bool = false
    ...
```

The outlets look like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var outSomeSwitch1: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var outSomeSwitch2: UISwitch!
```

Setting these switches is done in viewDidLoad() like so:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if newTracker.someVariable1 {
        outSomeSwtich1.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
    if newTracker.someVariable2 {
        outSomeSwitch2.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Can anyone think of why this would *not* function at random? The first instance of it was an iPhone 6s with the most recent OS, and the second instance was on a 7 with the most recent OS. Neither had other apps running in the background. I had my hands on them, but they were not hooked into my devel machine so I couldn't peek at what was going on, and I can't replicate the result on the 4, 5, 5s, 7, or iPad Air 2 that I have for testing.

The only other thing that is strange in my case is that sometimes the *Back* or *Next* button may not be a drag & drop segue. Sometimes they can use a bit of code to decide which screen to load next, or which screen *should* be previous.

```
@IBAction func actionNextUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        if newTracker.someVariable1 {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"viewSomeView1") as UIViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true)
        } else if newTracker.someVariable2 {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"viewSomeView2") as UIViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true)
        } else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"viewSomeView3") as UIViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Could the problem live in the way this loads a view?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: A quick point; using the `back` button with your `actionNextUpInside` code will not present a previous view controller. Your code will create a new instance of a view controller and return that. If you want to return to a previous view controller you will need to use `unwind` segues or `popToViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad()` is called once to set up the view after loading it from your storyboard. If you want to update the UI when the view appears, after briefly, going to some other view, you should use `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear()`.

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    outSomeSwitch1.setOn(newTracker.someVariable1, animated: true)
    outSomeSwitch2.setOn(newTracker.someVariable2, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: That could very well be it right there. I'll give it a spin and see if it solves things. Thanks so much!

Comment: Great point. Your code also deals with the situation that a `UISwitch` has been to set to `false` from `true` and needs to be updated. OP's code will not do this; it will only set `UISwitch`'s to `true`.

Comment: You're correct that it doesn't set things as false in this part. I haven't had an instance where a UISwitch has loaded with anything but an off state, so setting them (either way) has been left as a touch function, while the viewDidLoad() (and soon this new approach) just handled setting things to reflect user options. I'll definitely take this approach though. Just because I haven't seen one come in already set on doesn't mean it can't happen and make people flip out.